# implementation of a tcp socket service for notifing my mobile apps

Tags: asp.net, sockets

I want to create a socket on the client to listen for notifications from the server. Is there any example of a socket server built that I can use in my asp.net application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net is state-less you would need to build a windows service or windows application to publish a socket end-point unless you are looking at something like Comet?

Asp.net cannot fire server events if there is no intervention by a process or a user.
Can you describe your requirement a bit better?

Comment: I have a mobile app and the server send data from time to time to the app. If I use SignalR, I have to put the JS code inside a webview. Do you think I should go for SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR is a Server side and client side implementation of Comet it looks like a suitable solution for messaging purposes what are you attempting to build this might give more insight to a suitable solution.